# WildCard in NotResource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, identity-management

NotResource results in a shorter policy by listing only a few resources that should not match, rather than including a long list of resources that will match.

what will be the result of wildcard in NotResource?

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "NotAction": [
    "iam:*"
  ],
  "NotResource": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A policy statement element with `NotResource` applies to any resource that does *not* match the listed resource(s).  `*` matches any resource, so `NotResource` `*` ends up meaning "not any resource".  The policy will have no effect since it will match no resources.

I'm not sure AWS will let you create such a policy, but if it's allowed that's the effect it will have.